# Is it possible to set QuickBooks Online access token expiration or lifetime

Tags: java, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but the oAuth playground at:

https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/?ck=consumer_key&cs=consumer_secret

seems to suggest that it is. Along with consumer key/secret field, there's an access token expiry field. The subsequent URL that's used is:

[https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/SessionStart?grantUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fappcenter.intuit.com%2FPlayground%2FOAuth%2FBeginIAFlow%3Fconsumer_key%3D[my_consumer_key]%26consumer_secret%3D[my_consumer_secret]%26access_token_lifetime%3D300](https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/SessionStart?grantUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fappcenter.intuit.com%2FPlayground%2FOAuth%2FBeginIAFlow%3Fconsumer_key%3D%5bmy_consumer_key%5d%26consumer_secret%3D%5bmy_consumer_secret%5d%26access_token_lifetime%3D300)

The `access_token_lifetime` parameter at the end is specifying the access token lifetime in seconds, but I've tried inserting this parameter into my URL that's sent to both the request token API and the access token API (not both at the same time, just one or the other separately). For example, for the request token API, I've tried:

```
HttpParameters additionalParams = new HttpParameters();
additionalParams.put("oauth_callback", URLEncoder.encode(callback_url, "UTF-8"));
additionalParams.put("access_token_lifetime", "500");
ouathconsumer.setAdditionalParameters(additionalParams);

String signedRequestTokenUrl = ouathconsumer.sign(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL);
signedRequestTokenUrl += "&access_token_lifetime=500";
```

...and for the access token API:

```
HttpParameters additionalParams = new HttpParameters();
additionalParams.put("oauth_callback", "oob");
additionalParams.put("oauth_verifier", verifierCode);
additionalParams.put("access_token_lifetime", "500");
consumer.setAdditionalParameters(additionalParams);

String signedURL = consumer.sign(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL);
signedURL += "&access_token_lifetime=500";
```

Neither has worked. The oAuth process succeeds in both cases, and my developer account shows that a new connection has been establised. But that connection is still valid even after 500 seconds.

However, there's no mention of setting access token expiration time in the Intuit docs for the standard oAuth token expiration (180 days), so I hope that doesn't mean it's not possible:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app/implement_oauth_in_your_app/token_renewal_and_expiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to set your own token lifetime.

Why would anyone even need this?

Comment: I'm developing an application that will allow someone to create invoices in their QuickBooks account based on the contents of an Excel spreadsheet. This app will be publicly available on the Internet (for convenience) but it will only be used by a few people in a specific company to access one QB account. I don't want my app to have to mess around with usernames and passwords. So, anybody can use the app but you will only be able to affect the QB account that you authorize with oAuth. Since my app server is not storing uname/pass for users, I need access tokens to expire (after say, 24 hours).

Comment: I guess I have no choice, then. I'll have to get my app server to store any access tokens that are generated, keep track of how long they exist and call the disconnect API after X amount of time. It's not a huge hassle, but I can't get the disconnect API calls (using `IAPlatformClient#disconnect` from the API helper jar) to work. I get a timeout error everytime and the access token remains valid (it's a separate question I suppose, but if you know a likely cause/solution, I'd love to hear it).

Comment: So you're planning on just leaving a webpage out on the open internet which lets any non-authenticated person randomly push data to your client's QuickBooks file...? Does that sound a bit insecure to anyone else...? It should take 5 minutes to set up password protection on a directory via a script or web server config - why would you not just password protect the code?

Comment: No, anybody can use the app but if you want to use it, you have to connect to your QuickBooks (via oAUTH) account using the connect to QuickBooks button on the app home page. A HTTP session keeps track of the access token/secret for subsequent requests to the API, but the session expires after 30 minutes of inactivity. It just means that my clients have a QuickBooks username/password already, and so I don't have to make them come up with more usernames/passwords and have the server manage them. The user can disconnect too, but I want the tokens to expire in case they forget to disconnect.

Comment: I'm just to trying to be considerate to the QuickBooks API. This app will only be used a couple of times a week by one or two people, but I don't want loads of access tokens building up accidentally on QuickBooks end. Also, maybe there's a limit to the number of concurrently active tokens for an app...

Comment: Oh,and the disconnect API is working fine for me, it was a problem on my end.